# Is it possible in Hibernate to override entity field name in a child entity?

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm writing an app using Spring Boot, Hiberane and Spring Data.

I have two tables in the db: **tableA** and **tableB**.
They have some common fields but their id's,name's are different, also I've created a basic model for them to contain some common fields, right now it looks something like this:

```
// BaseModel
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseModel implements Serializable  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="common_field_1")
    private String commonField1;
    @Column(name="common_field_2")
    private String commonField2;
    @Column(name="common_field_3")
    private String commonField3;
}
```

---

```
// ExactModel 1
@Entity
@Table(name="table1" ,schema="schema") 
public class ExactModel1 extends BaseModel {

    @Id
    @Basic(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @Column(name="exact_model_id_1", nullable=false)
    private long exactModel1Id;

    private String exactField1;
}
```

---

```
// ExactModel 2
@Entity
@Table(name="table2" ,schema="schema") 
public class ExactModel2 extends BaseModel {

     @Id
     @Basic(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
     @Column(name="exact_model_id_2", nullable=false)
     private long exactModel2Id;

     private String exactField2;
}
```

And I have some generic logic which implements some general crud logic which works for classes which extend **BaseModel**:

```
public abstract class BaseServiceImpl<M extends BaseModel, R extends BaseRepository<M>> implements BaseService<M, Long> {

private final R repository;

public BaseServiceImpl(R repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
}

@Override
public M save(M model) {
    return repository.save(model);
}

@Override
public List<M> saveAll(List<M> models) {
    return repository.saveAll(models);
}

@Override
public M findById(Long id) {
    return repository.getOne(id);
}

@Override
public List<M> findAllById(List<Long> ids) {
    return repository.findAllById(ids);
}

@Override
public List<M> findAll() {
    return repository.findAll();
}

@Override
public M update(M model) {
    return repository.save(model);
}

@Override
public List<M> updateAll(List<M> models) {
    return repository.saveAll(models);
}

@Override
public void delete(M model) {
    repository.delete(model);
}

@Override
public void delteById(Long id) {
    repository.deleteById(id);
}

@Override
public void deleteInBatch(List<M> models) {
    repository.deleteInBatch(models);
}

@Override
public Long countModels() {
    return repository.count();
}
}
```

The thing is now I need to get somehow the id of the entity I work with in this generic logic, but there is no id field in BaseModel, so I can't just use `baseModel.getId()`.

**The question**: is it possible to define a **mock** id field in BaseModel and override it in the child classes, so I can use this id in the generic methods but Hibernate fills the actual ids on the runtime for me?

Comment: Maybe simply add abstract method getID in BaseModel and implement it in ExactModel1 and ExactModel2 to return their corresponding ids

Comment: @n1t4chi Tried you assumption, now I'm getting `org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity` though I have `@Id` on my id fields in ExactModel1  and ExactModel2

Comment: The solution was to mark `public abstract Long getId()` with `@Transient` . Thanks @n1t4chi, used your approach.